# move home from USB drive to new HDD on Laptop

Tags: command-line

I have new install on HDD with separate home on my laptop. I have old HDD mounted via USB How do I move it's home to the new drive? I know to use cp -Rf. I want to avoid any permissions problems. I copied home to the new drive but have problems. Folder and file icons are not right. Icons have padlock on them (I can open them) some ordinary folders have padlock and X on them. I have to enter password to open them. For example, Dogs folder (just has info about or dogs, never had to have root to open it) Rather than fix problems I want to know how to do this operation w/out any problems. Is there any preperations I need to do on either drive before I start?

Comment: Only a bit different than this: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
 If owership or permissions, see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dmrcErrors

Comment: I prefer the GUI **Grsync** makes it easy to see what is happening: https://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync/ . You could also use gparted to copy paste the /home partition and edit the /home UUID in etc/fstab. user names should be the same.